# Set all data from xml into a DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I am trying to set all the data from XML into a datagrid. This is my xaml code:

```
<datagrid x:name="dataGrid" horizontalalignment="Left" 
    autogeneratecolumns="False" height="271" 
    margin="10,10,0,0" verticalalignment="Top" width="491">
    IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME"
        Binding="{Binding NAME}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="UNIT"
        Binding="{Binding UNIT}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CURRENCYCODE"
        Binding="{Binding CURRENCYCODE}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="COUNTRY"
        Binding="{Binding COUNTRY}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RATE"
        Binding="{Binding RATE}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CHANGE"
        Binding="{Binding CHANGE}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</datagrid>
```

I try to put all the data in the grid with this code:

```
private void setData()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load("https://forex.boi.org.il/currency.xml");
    var data = doc.Root.Elements("CURRENCY");
    List information = new List();

    foreach (var code in data)
    {
        var nameV = code.Element("NAME").Value;
        var unitV = code.Element("UNIT").Value;
        var currencyCodeV = code.Element("CURRENCYCODE").Value;
        var currencyV = code.Element("COUNTRY").Value;
        var rateV = code.Element("RATE").Value;
        var changeV = code.Element("CHANGE").Value;

        Info row = new Info(nameV, unitV, currencyCodeV, currencyV, 
            rateV, changeV);

        information.SetValue(row);

    }
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = information;t unsecsses
}
```

In this row `information.SetValue(row);` I try to set INFO class into the list. I see that there is an option to write something that convert the xml to LIST and it was very easy but it now work.

i try this: data.ToList(); but i dont know how to do it.. help..

Comment: I think you forgot to finish your last sentence.

Comment: May I ask what `dataGrid.ItemsSource = information;t unsecsses` is meant to indicate?

Comment: What is the `List` class and its `SetValue(row)` method? Non generic `IList` in .NET is `ArrayList` and, as far as I know, it doesn't have `SetValue(Object)` method.

Comment: Should be `List<Info> information = new List<Info>();` and `information.Add(row);` I would say.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed your class' *public properties* and the *binding* match (`Info` class has all those properties mentioned in binding statements). Then you can try using `IEnumerable<Info>` or `List<Info>` for the `ItemsSource` :

```
.....
IEnumerable<Info> information = doc.Root
                                   .Elements("CURRENCY")
                                   .Select(o => new Info
                                             (
                                                (string)o.Element("NAME"),
                                                (string)o.Element("UNIT"),
                                                (string)o.Element("CURRENCYCODE"),
                                                (string)o.Element("COUNTRY"),
                                                (string)o.Element("RATE"),
                                                (string)o.Element("CHANGE")
                                             ));
dataGrid.ItemsSource = information;
```

Comment: Despite generally similar approach taken to overcome OP's fundamental problem, this answer anticipate several other possible problems (I'm sure you can see the differences in my code). I won't add lengthy explanation about that until I know that OP actually has one of those anticipated problems, or until someone asked why I proposed that approach.

Comment: @VDohnal And I didn't even talked about this until your comment, coz I'm not trying to make my answer looks better nor trying to win a prize here :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `SetData` method should look like this:

```
private void setData()
{
     var doc = XDocument.Load("https://forex.boi.org.il/currency.xml" );
     IEnumerable<Info> information = doc.Descendants("CURRENCY").Select(x => new Info()
     {
            nameV = x.Element("NAME").Value,
            unitV = x.Element("UNIT").Value,
            //etc...
     });
     dataGrid.ItemsSource = information;
}
```

In your attempt you have following problems:
It should be `List<Info> information = new List<Info>();` and `information.Add(row);`.

Do not forget to modify your XAML so that bindings of columns correspond with the names of properties in your `Info` class (`nameV`, `currencyV` etc.), so you will have it like this:     `Binding="{Binding nameV}"`